# how do i add =send= to this path ?https://mail.google.com

Tags: windows

how do i add =send= to this path to send at once ?https://mail.google.com/a/domain/?view=cm&fs=1&tf=1&source=mailto&to=WHOEVER%40COMPANY.COM&su=SUBJECTHERE&cc=WHOEVER%40COMPANY.COM&bcc=WHOEVER%40COMPANY.COM&body=PREPOPULATEDBODY

Comment: Actually this path : https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/?view=cm&ui=2&tf=0&fs=1&to=WHOEVER@COMPANY.COM&su=SUBJECTHERE&body=LINE1%0ALINE2

Comment: Looks like you're trying to create a link which will force someone to send an email. Not a good idea.

Comment: Why not? What's wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that; Google won't let you. I know of no email provider who would let you automatically trigger a sent email from a URL. That would allow a malicious website create and send spam on behalf of users.